# Embedding an absolute URL to a resource in a mail where Rails app is deployed on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, actionmailer

I want to embed a link to an article in a mail send by ActionMailer.
For that, I just want to place the absolute URL to and article in a plain text email. 
I am using the following line of code in the view.

```
<%= article_url(@article) %>
```

It works correctly on my development machine, i.e. I get http://localhost:3000/articles/14 for some article with ID=14.

But when I deploy to Heroku as production site, it localhost:3000 is not replaced with the URL of my production site. Do I need to configure that somewhere? Any hints? Thanks!

I am using Rails 3.

Answer (score 2):

See this option in `your_app/config/environments/production.rb`:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'your-domain.heroku.com' }
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but actually setting the default url options seems not to solve the problem. The view code <%= article_url(@article) %> raises an no routes found error...